# Is the statement about continuity of a linear function based on the closedness of its kernel always true?

Tags: functional-analysis, fake-proofs

I would like to answer this:

> Let $f : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a linear function with $V$ being a normed vector space (NVS). Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if $\text{ker} \, f := f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is closed.

However, I believe I've found a counterexample and would like some clarification. Consider the normed vector space of polynomials with the sup norm on $[0,1]$ and the differentiation operator $\frac{d}{dx}$. For this operator:

1. The kernel consists of constant polynomials, which correspond to real numbers and is closed in the space of all polynomials.
2. The operator seems unbounded since $\frac{\| \frac{d}{dx} x^n \|}{\| x^n \|} = n$, which implies that the operator is not continuous.

Given the above, it seems that we have a closed kernel but a non-continuous operator. Where is the flaw in my argument, or is the exercise statement incorrect?

Comment: Differentiation doesn't land in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I completely forgot about this. Feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: The kernel herein is an hyperplan, always closed in finite dimension and closed or dense when dimension is infinite.  Closed iff $f$ is continuous and dense iff $f$ non continuous (i.e non continuous in none point, as happens with the derivative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative map isn't a function from $V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ so it doesn't meet the criteria for the question.